# Using makefile patterns in function call

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a makefile which builds several platforms (windows, iOS, and so on) for different configurations (debug, release). I managed to make it work, it's building properly, but I'd like to make some of my rules more generic so that I don't have to repeat them for each configuration.

Each file is kept in a given folder structure. For instance, if building for iOS with a debug configuration, the resulting file is kept in ios/debug. As an example, I have rules for creating those directories:

```
define libdir
$(BINDIR)/$(strip $1)/$(strip $2)
endef

$(call libdir, ios, debug):
    mkdir -p $(call libdir, ios, debug)

$(call libdir, ios, release):
    mkdir -p $(call libdir, ios, release)
```

I'll have to repeat these rules for each configuration. It's not a lot, but it could become a pain to maintain. I would like to make these more generic, something like this (I know it doesn't work):

```
define libdir
$(BINDIR)/$(strip $1)/$(strip $2)
endef

$(call libdir, %, %):
    mkdir -p $(call libdir, ??, ??)
```

Which would create any directory with the given structure. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `strip`, and how would you like to invoke make to build, e.g., the debug configuration for iOS?

Comment: I'm using `strip` because sometimes I use spaces when calling functions, maybe due to typos. It just makes sure that space is not significant when passing function arguments

Comment: I have productions such as `iphone-debug`, `iphone-release`, and `iphone` for both

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could use a simple pattern rule instead.

```
%/debug %/release: %:
    mkdir -p $@
```

And then probably make each platform depend on these directories:

```
ios android osx windows linux: %: $(LIBDIR)/%/debug $(LIBDIR)/%/release
```

Answer (score 0):

A statement like:

```
define libdir
$(BINDIR)/$(strip $1)/$(strip $2)
endef

$(call libdir, %, %):
        mkdir -p $(call libdir, ??, ??)
```

simply strips the literal character `%`; the `strip` function is expanded when the pattern rule is parsed not when the rule matches.

But that's OK, because it doesn't make any sense the other way.  First of all you can't have multiple patterns in a target, so a rule like `$(BINDIR)/%/%` is not a legal pattern rule anyway.  Second, a pattern matches a set of characters; it doesn't matter what those characters are.  If you want to strip then you have to *strip the prerequisite* used to match that pattern rule, not strip the pattern rule.  E.g., somewhere else in your makefile you'll have a rule like:

```
foo: $(BINDIR)/$(FOO)/$(BAR)
```

that you intend to match that pattern: *that's* what you need to strip, not the target.

And just a note, but you don't need to use the function inside the recipe.  Why not just use `$@`?

```
$(BINDIR)/%:
        mkdir -p $@
```